# Swift - Clear TableView

Tags: swift2

I have a search which downloads a JSON file and displays the results in a TableView. If the user searches for something and gets a list of results, then searches for something else which returns 0 results. The first set of results is still in the TableView. I want to clear the TableView each time a new search starts to prevent that happening. I've tried setting the data source to nil and reloading the TableView but it's not working. Here's what I have:

```
var searchResults : [[String : AnyObject]]? = nil

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print("DEBUG: searchBarSearchButtonClicked")
    if searchBar.text > "" {

        //--- This isn't working ---
        searchResults = nil
        tableView.reloadData()
        //--------------------------

        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        dbSearcher.startSearch(searchBar.text!) { (results) -> () in
            self.searchResults = results
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

        searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchResults != nil {
        print("DEBUG: Result count \(searchResults!.count)")
        return searchResults!.count
    } else {
        print("DEBUG: Result count 0") //I don't see this other than when the ViewController first loads
        return 0
    }

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchResult")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = searchResults![indexPath.row]["Title"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = searchResults![indexPath.row]["Year"] as? String

    //Display cover
    let imageURL = searchResults![indexPath.row]["Poster"] as? String
    if imageURL != "N/A" {

        if let cover : UIImage = searchResults![indexPath.row]["Image"] as? UIImage {
            cell.imageView?.image = cover
        } else {
            //Use default cover while the correct image downloads
            //cell.imageView?.image = DEFAULT_COVER
            downloadCover(imageURL!, tableViewRow: indexPath.row)
        }

    } else {
        //Use default cover
        //cell.imageView?.image = DEFAULT_COVER
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: I tried the way you reset the table view and it works for me. The table gets emptied. In your question you write that you set your dataSource to nil. Do you still do that somewhere else?

Comment: No I only do it in searchBarSearchButtonClicked(...). When I say I set it to nil, I mean where I create tempDict as a nil dictionary and set searchResults = tempDict. I did try to just do searchResults = nil but it gave me an error.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting when trying to set `searchResults = nil`? It should not cause an error.

Comment: It must have been a typo lol. It does work now, but my TableView still isn't clearing. I'll update my code to show that change.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Don't use an optional type.**
Declare an non-optional empty array.

```
var searchResults : [[String : Any]]()
```

then `numberOfRowsInSection` can be just

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchResults.count
}
```

To clear the table view write

```
searchResults.removeAll()
tableView.reloadData()
```

No unwrapping, no checking for `nil`, no problems.

Comment: I've found the problem, it was my fault. I forgot to clear the results which are transferred in the callback from dbSearcher.startSearch(...). I have changed the variable as you suggested however, thanks. The only difference is it has to be declared as var searchResults : [[String : AnyObject]] = []

Answer (score 2):

This post was a long time ago, but for anyone interested, here is what I use in my app.

If you really want to use the `deleteRows` function (for animation purposes for instance), then you can do the following:

```
let count = self.tableView(self.tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: 0)
// insert action that deletes all your data from the model here
// e.g. self.arrayOfRows = []
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: (0..<count).map({ (i) in IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)}), with: .automatic)
```

What it basically does is convert the range `0..<count` to `[IndexPath]` values and instructs the table view to delete those paths, using the `deleteRows` method.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
tableView.getItems().clear();
```